# How do I use my meta from the template in my script in vue?

Tags: vue.js, seo, meta-tags

I have a vue application which I want to have meta for all the individual route pages I just need to know how to set the meta after I've got them from the template heres what I've got so far.

```
<template>
<head>

    <meta name="description" content="Description of page"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Slider",
  created(){
        document.title = "Title | Site Name"
        document.head.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').content
        document.head.querySelector('meta[name="keywords"]').content
        document.head.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').content
  },
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to set this in the script on each route page rather than having to use vue-meta or having to set something up in route?

Comment: You just want to get meta right ? maybe you can create composables and call it when you need it ?

Comment: Are you using vue-router?

Comment: Yes I am using vue router but it would work better for me if the meta was on each vue page as a pose to in the router